# spring rabbitmq automatic recovery enable

Tags: spring, spring-rabbit

```
@Bean
public StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor() { 
     return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful()  
    .maxAttempts(5)
    .backOffOptions(1000, 2.0, 10000) 
    .build();   
}
```

Can we use this bean for spring-rabbitmq automatic recovery because spring rabbit does not supports

```
factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
factory.setNetworkRecoveryInterval(10000);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what your question is.

The retry @Bean is for retrying when your application listener fails to process a message.

The recovery settings are for recovering connections/channels when the connection to the broker is lost.

Spring AMQP has its own re-connection (`recoveryInterval` on the listener container) so it's not really needed to set the rabbit client options. When using Spring AMQP < 1.4.0, you must **not** set these options.

If you are using Spring AMQP 1.4.0 or greater, you can set those on the underlying connection factory, [as described in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#connection-factory) but it's not really necessary because Spring AMQP will reconnect for you.

Comment: thanks gary russell my exact issue i am having a service which runs for many days.that service will be never changed.but all other service will change.but some time that service lose the connection to rabbitmq but rabbitmq is still up.what i can do for that to avoid connection loss

Comment: If connection lost then message will not be recovered. Recovery means that message will be sent to queue back - this is default behaviour. After the connection exception was thrown the message on   RabbitMQ side will be marked as unacked and will be sent to another consumer